# LVM RAID10 "Won't be synchronised" - What does it mean?

Tags: lvm, software-raid, raid10

I was [creating an LVM RAID 10](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/LVM#LVM_RAID10) across 4 physical volumes (each 3TB) when I got the following error message:

`WARNING: New raid10 won't be synchronised. Don't read what you didn't write!`

[image]

My googling came up with nothing about what this means. Does this mean that the mirroring of the raid will not work and if a single drive fails, all the data is lost?

Comment: It's just a warning since you have used option **--nosync**. [From The man page of **lvcreate**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lvcreate). "Specifying the optional argument **--nosync** will cause the creation of the mirror to skip the initial **resynchronization**. Any data written afterwards will be mirrored, but the original contents will not be copied. This is useful for skipping a potentially long and resource intensive initial sync of an empty device."

Comment: silly me, I must have read that command 10 times and not seen that `--no-sync` part and looked that up. Can you put that comment as an answer and I will mark it as correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a warning since you have used option **--nosync**.

[From The man page of lvcreate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lvcreate).

"Specifying the optional argument **--nosync** will cause the creation of the mirror to skip the initial **resynchronization**. Any data written afterwards will be mirrored, but the original contents will not be copied. This is useful for skipping a potentially long and resource intensive initial sync of an empty device."